# Adding Assets on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I add an assets file for sprites on Unity? I have clicked on the add sign but there is no option saying: "sprites". When I click on it it simply just doesn't have the option on the bar.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow Unity official manual:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html

1. Create your sprite as image with your preferred graphic software
2. Add your image to Unity (drag & drop or just + button)
3. Change texture type in Ispector as "Sprite"

[image]